# two filehandlers of two different loggers get the same content

Tags: python, email, logging

I wrote a script that collects the event logs from cloudwatch, writes them to two files then sends the content of each file by mail. As I want to receive two emails, each loggers has a different type of logs, I created two loggers:

```
logLevel = logging.INFO
doWait = object()
if os.path.exists ('.debug'):
    logLevel = logging.DEBUG
logger1 = logging.getLogger()
logger2 = logging.getLogger()
logger1.setLevel(logLevel)
logger2.setLevel(logLevel)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s')
fileHandler1 = os.path.join('/tmp/', 'error-admin-' + datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') +  '.log')
fileHandler2 = os.path.join('/tmp/', 'error-user-' + datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') +  '.log')
fh1 = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileHandler)
fh2 = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileHandler2)
fh1.setLevel(logLevel)
fh2.setLevel(logLevel)
fh1.setFormatter(formatter)
fh2.setFormatter(formatter)
logger1.addHandler(fh1)
logger2.addHandler(fh2)
```

in the main, I call functions like that:

```
function1(arg1,arg2,logger1)
function2(arg1,arg2,logger2)
```

Now, my problem is, that when I execute my script, I get the same content in the both filehandlers, even that I separated the loggers. Why does that happen?

Comment: You are doing exactly the same thing with your two loggers, why should it be two different results ?

Comment: each logger has a different filehandler, and when I call the functions that collect the events, I specify in which file I want to write the logs by calling eather logger1 or logger2 @iFlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `logger1` and `logger2` both point at the *root* `Logger` underneath.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects): `Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.`

You need two separate `Logger` objects:

```
logger1 = logging.getLogger('error-admin')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('error-user')
```